# bind_result Is not fetching the results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What's wrong in this statement because it's not printing the result and showing blank page I have ask the same question but little different few hours ago but not getting the right solution

Here is the code

```
    if(isset($_GET['ID'])){

    $page_id = $_GET['ID'];

    $select_query = $con->prepare("select ID, Title, image, Cost, Vid, content from mobs where ID=?"); 

    $select_query->execute()
    $select_query->bind_result($post_id, $post_title, $post_image, $post_cost, $post_vid, $post_content);

while ($select_query->fetch())
echo $post_id ,"<br>",
     $post_title;
 {
```

Comment: Did you forget to set the ID parameter?

Comment: Every other thing is alright it is giving me this error
`syntax error, unexpected '$select_query' (T_VARIABLE) ` on the 5th line where bind_result is

Comment: -1 for accepting the MOST AWFUL answer possible. I hope you'll be banned from asking questions

Comment: -1 for accepting an answer that does not solve your problem the right way, use PDO when working with database connections or at least mysqli functions in combination with prepared statements.

Comment: @YourCommonSense No matter how awful it is but it helped me dude because I was searching and searching for hours and didn't find my answer which helped me and this simple answer helped me and my problem solved I don't know why people like you just don't want someone to be happy May GOD keep people like you away from the world

Comment: In fact, your problems only started here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You forgot to parametize the `$_GET["ID"]` to your query:

```
if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT ID, Title, image, Cost, Vid, content FROM mobs WHERE ID=?")){

  $stmt->bind_param("i", $_GET["ID"]); /* This is the part you're missing from your original post */
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($post_id, $post_title, $post_image, $post_cost, $post_vid, $post_content);

  while($stmt->fetch()){ /* And I fixed your fetching of arrays */
    printf("%s<br>", $post_title); /* JUST SET WHAT YOU WANT TO OUTPUT HERE */
  } /* END OF WHILE LOOP */

} /* END OF PREPARED STATEMENT */
```

Comment: Thank you so so so so so so Much I love you bro You solved it I was going to die You solved it bro

Comment: No problem. And what unexpected ',' error? Anyway, goodluck with what you're doing.

Comment: @Logan I just change it to `$select_query =mysqli_query($con,`

Comment: ... and more than that - a solution that diverts the OP from the right way